# No institute on poster

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

In the part that precedes `\begin{document}`, I would like to remove the institute line, but leaving the argument empty does not work. How would I do it?

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster

\usetheme{confposter} % Use the confposter theme supplied with this template
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tasks}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=blue,bg=white} % Colors of the block titles
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Colors of the body of blocks
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=blue!70} % Colors of the highlighted block titles
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=blue!10} % Colors of the body of highlighted blocks
% Many more colors are available for use in beamerthemeconfposter.sty

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in} % A0 width: 46.8in
\setlength{\paperheight}{36in} % A0 height: 33.1in
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.04\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.44\paperwidth} % Width of one column
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.84\paperwidth} % Width of two columns
\setlength{\threecolwid}{1.26\paperwidth} % Width of three columns
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} % Reduce the top margin size
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{graphicx}  % Required for including images

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{{Mathematically Modeling the Motion of Cells in Porous Media}} % Poster title

\author{Ahaan S. Rungta, Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT)} % Author(s)

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where's `confposter` from? I don't have this theme here.

Comment: And of course your document isn't complete at all...

Comment: I've compiled your edited document. It works with `\institute{}` or omitting that macro. However, I had to disable the `confposter` theme. I asked you already about half an hour ago where this strange theme is from.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I managed to find the theme here: http://www.njohnston.ca/2009/08/latex-poster-template/

Comment: @Grimler: Oh, thank you -- you've done the work which should be done by the O.P. ;-) (Again, thank you, seriously!)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yeah, I agree, not clear how to find it. No problem. The problem seem to be in the headline definition, you can probably make a more elegant solution by redefining the headline.

Answer (score 2):

The error is the incomplete `\setbeamercolor{block body}` command in the above document. It misses a full `bg=...}` statement:

```
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,b
```

`\institute{}` works as well as just omitting the line completely.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster

%\usetheme{confposter} % Use the confposter theme supplied with this template
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tasks}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=ngreen,bg=white} % Colors of the block titles
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=green}

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in} % A0 width: 46.8in
\setlength{\paperheight}{36in} % A0 height: 33.1in
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.06\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.42\paperwidth} % Width of one column
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.84\paperwidth} % Width of two columns
\setlength{\threecolwid}{1.26\paperwidth} % Width of three columns
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} % Reduce the top margin size
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{graphicx}  % Required for including images

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{{Mathematically Modeling the Motion of Cells in Porous Media}} % Poster title

\author{Ahaan S. Rungta, Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT)} % Author(s)

\institute{} % Institution(s)

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, I wonder why the O.P. sets the institute to the `\author{..}` field and drops `\institute` (Lack of space?)

Comment: Sorry, there was some problem when posting, some text got cut off. I have edited my post and your post is now moot -- it does not work for me.

Comment: @AhaanS.Rungta: And again your post above is not complete. My answer was (and perhaps is still) valid

Comment: I don't see how it's not complete now.

Comment: @AhaanS.Rungta: It has no `\maketitle`, not even `\begin{document}...\end{document}` -- that's what I call **not complete**

Comment: Fine. Edited. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you omit `\institute{...}` in this theme the compilation fails due to the creator putting a line break after the `\insertinstitute`-command. The same would happen if you omit `\author{...}` or `\title{...}`.

Easiest fix (if you don't want to edit the theme) would be to actually use the `\institute`-command as you are suppose to, i.e. use

```
\title{Mathematically Modeling the Motion of Cells in Porous Media}
\author{Ahaan S. Rungta}
\institute{Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT)}
```

You can always change the font size with for example `\institute{\large Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT)}`

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot. However, I am eagerly trying to not use the third line. Is there a way I can fix that?

Comment: @AhaanS.Rungta Yeah, by redefining the template, can perhaps look at it next year (i.e. in >12 h).

Why exactly do you want to omit it? To get the author and institute on the same line?

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded zip archive from site you have mentioned.
You can not omit `\institute`, but you can put

```
\institute{\~{}}
```

and everything works fine without error messages .
In your code also put:

```
\institute{\~{}} after `\author` command and it will work
```

edited:
see comments below `\institute{\mbox{}}` is right solution

Comment: That would produce a tilde accent over nothing; is perhaps `\institute{~}` what you had in mind? Maybe better, `\institute{\mbox{}}`.

Comment: in `lualatex` i had no tilde..I have not tried other engines, but you  are right ,pdflatex gives tilde :) .... \institute{\mbox{}} is right solution